# error in labelled point object pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am writing a function

1. which takes a RDD as input
2. splits the comma separated values
3. then convert each row into labelled point object
4. finally fetch the output as a dataframe

   ```
   code: 

   def parse_points(raw_rdd):

       cleaned_rdd = raw_rdd.map(lambda line: line.split(","))
       new_df = cleaned_rdd.map(lambda line:LabeledPoint(line[0],[line[1:]])).toDF()
       return new_df


   output = parse_points(input_rdd)
   ```

upto this if I run the code, there is no error it is working fine.

But on adding the line,

```
 output.take(5)
```

I am getting the error:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task   0 in stage 129.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in s    stage 129.0 (TID 152, localhost): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):

Py4JJavaError       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-100-a68c448b64b0> in <module>()
 20 
 21 output = parse_points(raw_rdd)
 ---> 22 print output.show()
```

Please suggest me what is the mistake.

Comment: `List[List[str]]` doesn't fit [following description](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html#pyspark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint) _Vector of features for this point (NumPy array, list,  pyspark.mllib.linalg.SparseVector, or scipy.sparse column matrix)_, does it? So what makes you think it should work? At least check docstrings...

Comment: @zero323 i m sorry pretty new to spark, not able to understand your point. Can u explain it more,in case if u can?

Comment: @zero323 infact it is working fine If  i am not trying to convert it into dataframe using .toDF()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you had no errors until you execute the action:

```
 output.take(5)
```

Is due to the nature of spark, which is lazy.
i.e. nothing was execute in spark until you execute the action "take(5)"

You have a few issues in your code, and I think that you are failing due to extra "[" and "]" in [line[1:]]

So you need to remove extra "[" and "]" in [line[1:]] (and keep only the line[1:])

Another issue which you might need to solve is the lack of dataframe schema.

i.e. replace "toDF()" with "toDF(["features","label"])"
This will give the dataframe a schema.

Comment: i tried it, it throws an error where I am trying to convert it into DF.

Comment: In my answer I've added a reference to another issue which you might need to fix - the lack of dataframe schema

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
>>> raw_rdd.map(lambda line: line.split(",")) \
...     .map(lambda line:LabeledPoint(line[0], [float(x) for x in line[1:]])
```

Comment: Can you  expand on your code and why it might fix the error?