# converting pyspark dataframe to labelled point object

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-sql

```
df:
[Row(split(value,,)=[u'21.0', u'1',u'2']),Row(split(value,,)=[u'22.0', u'3',u'4'])]
```

how to convert each row in df into a `LabeledPoint` object, which consists of a label and features, where the first value is the label and the rest 2 are features in each row.

```
mycode:

df.map(lambda row:LabeledPoint(row[0],row[1: ]))
```

It does not seem to work, new to spark hence any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error in labelled point object pyspark](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38887157/error-in-labelled-point-object-pyspark)

Comment: @LostInOverflow no it is not, this is from dataframe and that was from RDD.

Comment: @LostInOverflow can u suggest me something for this?

Comment: Have you look at this question? [stackoverflow question about spark/labelledpoint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32556178/create-labeledpoints-from-spark-dataframe-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to obtain an `RDD` you need to create a function to parse your `Array` of `String`.

```py
a = sc.parallelize([([u'21.0', u'1',u'2'],),([u'22.0', u'3',u'4'],)]).toDF(["value"])
a.printSchema()

#root
#|-- value: array (nullable = true)
#|    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

To achieve this check my function.

```py
def parse(l):
  l = [float(x) for x in l]

  return LabeledPoint(l[0], l[1:])
```

After defining such function, `map` your `DataFrame` in order to `map` its internal `RDD`.

```py
a.map(lambda l: parse(l[0])).take(2)

# [LabeledPoint(21.0, [1.0,2.0]), LabeledPoint(22.0, [3.0,4.0])]
```

Here you can find the [published notebook](https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/2485090270202665/2400794110066361/8589256059752547/latest.html) where I tested everything.

PD: If you use `toDF` you will obtain two columns (features and label).